# Python: Lazy DB from CSV data?

Tags: database, csv, python

I've got a relatively small (<100K) numerical CSV dataset that I want to process and graph with some numpy and pylab utilities, and it occurred to me that there's probably a better way of processing the data than ridiculous custom if-ladders for siphoning out the relevent experimental scenarios and comparisons.

If this data were in a DB rather than a CSV this wouldn't be a problem, but throwing together a 'real' db instance for the sake of this seems to be overkill. Is there a pythonic solution to what I'm looking for?

TL;DR Want to query CSV files like a DB / move CSV's into a mini-db.

Comment: Hi Andrew, did you find what you needed?

Comment: Ended up going pytables as per @eat's suggestion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without knowing any specific details (at all) of your case, I'll expect that you'll find eventually one of the following ladders as a dominant one for your case:

- Simply just use the built in Python [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html).

  - However, if the relational model is not a necessity then [pytables](https://www.pytables.org/) may be the way to go on.

    - Perhaps still, [structured arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) can provide the necessary functionality.

      - But plenty can be still achieved with just proper usage of plain [logic functions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.logic.html).

        - After all, get acquainted to live with your `ridiculous custom if-ladders`.

Obviously, any of the ladders sketched above will posses its specific pros and cons, depending on the actual case. Thus a really careful mix of them may eventually yield to best 'overall' result.

Comment: that would be interesting, but sqlite does not support csv as a backend, as far as I checked. I may be wrong though

Comment: @Stefano: No, not as a backend, but anyway it's very straightforward to populate the database from csv, as I believe would just fit to OPs case. Thanks

Comment: Just use a memory-only database in sqlite, and populate it from the csv file.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) could help you out. In particular the [query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) function.

Pandas can also do [joins](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) but at that point I would switch to SQL.
A tiny database wrapper is [dataset](https://dataset.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

I once started to write a library of utilities called wavemol. One subpackage I developed was wavemol.fileaccess, which contains a CSV parsing class, which allows to access the file in a more practical way. Check here the methods provided.

[check here the source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~wavemol/wavemol/wavemol.fileaccess/view/head:/lib/wavemol/fileaccess/general/__init__.py)

you may need to install wavemol.core first. I am not actively developing this code anymore, but if you are interested and this stuff does the trick for you, I may find some time to refocus on it a bit and put it back on track (of course help is welcome, but not necessary to make it a little better). I sort of lost interest into it because I changed job and I didn't need this stuff anymore.